# Java String replace all using regex with lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to get a normalized URI from the incoming HTTP Request to print in the logs. This will help us to compute stats & other data by this normalized URI.

To normalize, I'm trying to do String replace using regex on the requestURI with `x` for all numeric & alphanumeric strings except version (eg. v1):

```java
String str = "/v1/profile/abc13abc/13abc/cDe12/abc-bla/text_tw/HELLO/test/random/2234";
str.replaceAll("/([a-zA-Z]*[\\d|\\-|_]+[a-zA-Z]*)|([0-9]+)","/x");
```

This results in

```
/x/profile/x/x/x/x/x/HELLO/test/random/x
```

I want to get the result as (do not replace `v1`)

```
/v1/profile/x/x/x/x/x/HELLO/test/random/x
```

I tried using skip look ahead

```
String.replaceAll("/(?!v1)([a-zA-Z]*[\d|\-|_]+[a-zA-Z]*)|([0-9]+)","/x");
```

But not helping. Any clue is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a "guess my original String" question?

Comment: *do not replace v1-v4* - no idea what this means.

Comment: Please show the Input String and the expected result.  And don't use code to explain what you are trying to do. Write it out.

Comment: Apologies. Updated the question with original String.

Comment: Why are you punishing the poor soul (possibly yourself) who will have to read this code in the future, by using such an unwieldy regular expression?  I would suggest a simple non-regex alternative, but honestly, I can’t tell what you’re trying to do.  Do you always want to preserve the first two path components, and any subsequent components which contain no digits?

Comment: @VGR I've added more context. Hope they answer your questions.

Comment: I’m still not clear on what the rules are.  Do you always preserve the first two path components?  What determines which path components are replaced with `x`?

Comment: @VGR Thanks for asking. I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```java
/(?:(?!v[1-4])[a-zA-Z]*[0-9_-]+[a-zA-Z]*|[0-9]+)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/dhSsJl/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      v                        'v'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [1-4]                    any character of: '1' to '4'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9_-]+                 any character of: '0' to '9', '_', '-'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

Answer (score 1):

With the added explanation, here is how I would approach it.

- create a list of the elements spliting on `/` starting with the second one.
- initialize a string builder with the first element.
- then simply iterate over a sublist starting with the second element. Use `String.matches` to determine whether to replace with an x.

```
List<String> pathElements = Arrays.asList(str.substring(1).split("/"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/" + pathElements.get(0));
for(String pe : pathElements.subList(1,pathElements.size())) { 
    sb.append("/").append(pe.matches(".*[\\d-_].*") ? "x" : pe);
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

prints

```
/v1/profile/x/x/x/x/x/HELLO/test/random/x
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using one large regular expression that will be quite difficult for people to understand and maintain in the future (including yourself, probably), I would opt for using a few lines, which make your logic more apparent:

```
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(path.split("/"));
parts.replaceAll(
    p -> !p.matches("v\\d+") && p.matches(".*[-_\\d].*") ? "x" : p);
path = String.join("/", parts);
```

Comment: I like your approach.  But the OP said alphanumeric or numeric so you need to include, at  a minimum, the `-` and `_` characters. in your regex.

Comment: @WJS Are `-` and `_` considered numeric?  I assumed “numeric” meant digits.

Comment: It's a reasonable question.  I had to look it up to be certain based on the OP's expected answer.   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alphanumeric.  This is just one thing that should have been clarified in the question.  Another was `v1`.  Does that simply represent the root  of the path and can be anything  or is it literally `v1` or `v` followed by a digit?